# Netbeans problem with file permisions

Tags: filesystem, netbeans

After installing netbeans 7.40 and using it for java projects the following problem came up.
After creating accidentally a class,when I try to delete it I get a message saying

```
Error : permission denied
```

Anyone any idea why is this happening?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10.
I installed netbeans downloading `netbeans-7.4-javase-linux.sh` from netbeans site.

Also when I `cd /usr/local/netbeans-7.4/bin` and `sudo ./netbeans` things are OK.

Comment: have you installed it in /home or in /(root directory) , possibly its in / directory , just go to installed folder then right click on it and change permission. or use sudo chmod 755 /path/of/folder and provide your password..same do it for your workspace . it will set all permissions for future and you will not need to change permissions..

Comment: It is installed in /usr/local.
I did what you said but still the same.
Also to be sure, did you mean to change the permissions of the folder ie. /usr/local/netbeans-7.4

Comment: yeah..and as i think Ubuntu 13.10 itself is a problem and it could be one of the registered bug, as I had the same issue with Eclipse kepler and Spring tool suite IDE's.

Answer (score 0):

well as you can easily use it with sudo ,just create a netbeans.desktop by

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/netbeans.desktop
```

and then enter these lines

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Netbeans
Comment=Netbeans IDE
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= netbeans
Icon=netbeans  (or path of your icons .xpm file in the installation folder)
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Development,IDE;
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow
StartupNotify=false
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= netbeans
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

save it and then restart your PC once .press power key for dash and search for netbeans open it. hope it will work ,if it wont then register it as a bug as its a known issue on 13.10.